Postgres usage always using 100 cpu usage
In certain interval (like 60 minutes), postgres always uses 100%cpu. This problem is just starting last Thursday. I had to manually to kill the pid through HTOP. The one that makes me confused is command always changing, sometimes its command is "HTOP", but in 60 minutes interval when problem occur, it changes to "IRQBalance" or "SYSTEMD". It never happened before, and just occurred recently. Can someone help me?




It looks like your postgresql instance has been hacked (for example, because of you had presented postgresql port to Internet, and also had weak password or allowed access without password on postgresql superuser account) and now used by someone for mining or whatever.

how can you tell?

"how can i tell" what?

@RabbanKeyak How can you tell OP was hacked? Random CPU spikes are not necessarily indicative of that. In fact, mining would result in a mostly non-stop continuous spike.

it can be mining, because it makes sense for hacker. but probably it's encrypting of the database also.
and about "OP was hacked"... not necessary ofc. the postgres instance either hacked, or tuned for calculating something time to time using postgresql ability to create and execute files (if the commands runs with postgres superuser privilage), and running processes which names are randomly camouflaged to system processes names. probably it's definitely what OP or someone in his team made with the instance by itself ofc, i can't be sure for 100%.

@J.D.  Because we have seen it before, and is the only thing which makes sense.  It is a "continuous" spike, he said he has to kill it manually to make it go away, and then it comes back after about an hour.
